# How is this C++ function working differently than the equivalent java function?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to implement a Java version of the following C++ algorithm:

```
void constructPrintLIS(int arr[], int n)
{
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > L(n);

    L[0].push_back(arr[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if ((arr[i] > arr[j]) &&
                (L[i].size() < L[j].size() + 1))
            {
                L[i] = L[j];
                cout << true << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << false << endl;
            }
        }

        L[i].push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    std::vector<int> max = L[0];

    for (std::vector<int> x : L)
    {
        if (x.size() > max.size())
        {
            max = x;
        }
    }

    printLIS(max);
}
```

Here is the Java version

```
private static List<Integer> getLongestIncreasingSubsequence(
        List<Integer> sequence
        )
{   
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cache = 
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(sequence.size());
    // Populate the elements to avoid a NullPointerException
    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++)
    {
        cache.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    cache.get(0).add(sequence.get(0));

    // start from the first index, since we just handled the 0th
    for(int i = 1; i < sequence.size(); i++)
    {
        // Add element if greater than tail of all existing subsequences
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if((sequence.get(i) > sequence.get(j)) 
                    && (cache.get(i).size() < cache.get(j).size() + 1))
            {
                cache.set(i, cache.get(j));
            }
        }
        cache.get(i).add(sequence.get(i));                  
    }

    // Find the longest subsequence stored in the cache and return it
    List<Integer> longestIncreasingSubsequence = cache.get(0);
    for(List<Integer> subsequence : cache)
    {
        if(subsequence.size() > longestIncreasingSubsequence.size())
        {
            longestIncreasingSubsequence = subsequence;
        }
    }
    return longestIncreasingSubsequence;
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing differently. The C++ algorithm prints the correct result when the test sequence is `{9766, 5435, 624, 6880, 2660, 2069, 5547, 7027, 9636, 1487}`, with the correct result being `624, 2069, 5547, 7027, 9636`. However, the Java version that I have written returns an incorrect result of `624, 6880, 2660, 2069, 5547, 7027, 9636, 1487` and I don't understand why. I have tried tracing it in the debugger, and I can't figure out what is going wrong.

I tried adding a print statement indicating whether the if statement evaluated to true/false each time, and compared it with the C++ program, and it was the same, so that isn't the problem.

I suspect it is something to do with a subtle difference between a vector and an ArrayList, but I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that in Java, the cache contains *references* to lists, whereas in C++ it contains the lists themselves.

Thus, in C++

```
L[i] = L[j];
```

copies the list at index `j` to index `i`, whereas in Java

```
cache.set(i, cache.get(j));
```

copies a reference. That means, that when you subsequently add items to the one, they are also added to the other.

Maybe use

```
cache.set(i, new ArrayList<>(cache.get(j)));
```

so that you create a copy, like in C++.

Comment: This would make sense with what I am seeing in the debugger! But how does your proposed solution create a copy? I'm not following.

Comment: @Airhead `ArrayList(Collection)` is a constructor which copies the collection passed in.